# How to apply default and None operation names when constructing operations with Java Tensorflow API?

Tags: java, tensorflow

Many tf operations have optional/default 'name' argument, but it seems
there is no way to use the default value or avoid specifying it when
constructing operations with Java API. So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use default operation name when building it? If so, what should I pass to `opBuilder` method to use default value "range" for Range operation (or any other)?
2. Is it possible to pass no name (None value in Python)? If so, what should I pass to `opBuilder` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "many tf operations have optiona/default 'name' argument", I take it to mean that you're talking about the Python API for TensorFlow, where functions like [`tf.add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) take a 'name' argument.

The default in these cases is the name of the operation, with suffixes like `_<number>` added to avoid collisions. For example, in Python:

```
print(tf.add(1, 1).op.name) # Prints 'Add'
print(tf.add(1, 1).op.name) # Prints 'Add_1'
```

The handling of these "default" values comes from Python wrapping code, see: [tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L2462)

The Java `opBuilder` doesn't provide this convenience and you must explicitly specify a name that does not conflict with an existing node in the graph.

That said, progress is being made to generate wrapper Java functions for each TensorFlow operation, which will result in the convenience, similar to Python, where the name of the operation in the graph can be elided. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7149 for details.

Long story short, no, for now you must explicitly specify the operation name. When https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7149 is resolved, it should be more convenient to generate graphs in Java.

Hope that helps.